# how to create Synapse serverless pool partition table similar to hive

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

In hive we can create hive partition table as

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testdb.test_table(name string, age int)
PARTITIONED BY (dept string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/path/to/dataFile/';
```

for files spread across locations like:

```
/path/to/dataFile/dept1
/path/to/dataFile/dept2
/path/to/dataFile/dept3
```

and then we can update the partition like

```
ALTER TABLE testdb.table1 ADD PARTITION (dept='dept1') LOCATION '/path/to/dataFile/dept1';
ALTER TABLE testdb.table1 ADD PARTITION (dept='dept2') LOCATION '/path/to/dataFile/dept2';
ALTER TABLE testdb.table1 ADD PARTITION (dept='dept3') LOCATION '/path/to/dataFile/dept3';
```

In Azure  our files are spread in a container in different folders . I need to create a partition external table in the synapse serverless pool .The syntax i am following is

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [testdb].[test1]
(
[STUDYID] varchar(2000) ,[SITEID] varchar(2000) )
WITH
(
    LOCATION = '/<abc_location>/csv/archive/',
    DATA_SOURCE = [datalake],
    FILE_FORMAT = [csv_comma_values]
)
```

I was checking the azure docs but didn't find any relevant documentation for this . Is there any way we can achieve something similar to hive code.

Answer (score 0):

Partition External table is currently not available in Azure Synapse.

[Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop#location-1) starts from the root folder and by specifying `/**`, you can return the files from subfolders. The external table will skip the files starts with underscore `_` and period `.`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sample_table
 ( 
   firstname varchar(50),
   lastname varchar(50)
 )  
WITH (
  LOCATION = '/csv/**',
  DATA_SOURCE = blob_storage,  
  FILE_FORMAT = csv_file_format
)
```